# Java regex from Perl-type regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to extract hours, minutes, seconds, and nanoseconds from a string time stamp in a log file.Here is the input string I am testing with:

```
 SOME_TEXT,+09:30:01.040910105,SOME_TEXT,SOME_TEXT,SOME_TEXT
```

In Perl/Python, I would use the following regex to group the fields I am interested in:

```
 (\d\d)\:(\d\d)\:(\d\d)\.(\d{9})
```

You can verify that the regex works with the test string at http://regexpal.com if you're curious.

So I tried to write a simple Java program that can extract the fields:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Driver
{
  static public void main(String[] args)
  {
    String t = new String("SOME_TEXT,+09:30:01.040910105,SOME_TEXT,SOME_TEXT,SOME_TEXT");
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(\\d\\d):(\\d\\d):(\\d\\d)\\.(\\d{9})");
    Matcher matches = regex.matcher(t);
    for (int i=1; i<matches.groupCount(); ++i)
    {
      System.out.println(matches.group(i));
    }
  }
}
```

My regex did not translate correctly, however.  The following exception shows that it did not find any matches:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
   at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:485)
   at Driver.main(Driver.java:12)
```

How would I properly translate the regex from Perl/Python style to Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex itself is fine. There are, however, two problems with the code:

1. you need to call [`Matcher.find()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29);
2. you need to fix the `for` loop (it should use `<=` instead of `<`).

Here is the corrected version:

```
public class Driver
{
  static public void main(String[] args)
  {
    String t = new String("SOME_TEXT,+09:30:01.040910105,SOME_TEXT,SOME_TEXT,SOME_TEXT");
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(\\d\\d):(\\d\\d):(\\d\\d)\\.(\\d{9})");
    Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(t);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        for (int i=1; i<=matcher.groupCount(); ++i)
        {
          System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
        }
    }
  }
}
```

This prints out:

```
09
30
01
040910105
```

Answer (score 2):

Java breaks the perl-style, introducing complexity where it need not be. If you want to do regular expressions in Java the right way, take a look on [MentaRegex](http://mentaregex.soliveirajr.com). Below some examples:

The method *matches* returns a boolean saying whether we have a regex match or not.

```
matches("Sergio Oliveira Jr.", "/oliveira/i" ) => true
```

The method *match* returns an array with the groups matched. So it not only tells you whether you have a match or not but it also returns the groups matched in case you have a match.

```
match("aa11bb22", "/(\\d+)/g" ) => ["11", "22"]
```

The method *sub* allows you perform substitutions with regex.

```
sub("aa11bb22", "s/\\d+/00/g" ) => "aa00bb00"
```

Support global and case-insensitive regex.

```
match("aa11bb22", "/(\\d+)/" ) => ["11"]
match("aa11bb22", "/(\\d+)/g" ) => ["11", "22"]
matches("Sergio Oliveira Jr.", "/oliveira/" ) => false
matches("Sergio Oliveira Jr.", "/oliveira/i" ) => true
```

Allows you to change the escape character in case you don't like to see so many '\'.

```
match("aa11bb22", "/(\\d+)/g" ) => ["11", "22"]
match("aa11bb22", "/(#d+)/g", '#' ) => ["11", "22"]
```

Answer (score 0):

By default java regexs match against the whole string, you have to add .* to the beginning and end:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(".*(\\d\\d):(\\d\\d):(\\d\\d)\\.(\\d{9}).*");
```

and that should work, with the other corrections to your for loop as necessary :-)

Answer (score 0):

oh,no!
I copied your codes and wrapped with `if (matches.find()) {  ...}` then worked. you need this.

and nanoseconds was missing. you should do this change:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= matches.groupCount(); ++i)
-------------------^
```